# vswprintf() without buffer size crashes on small buffer instead of EOF. How to pass buffer size

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-2009

Using Borland C++ Builder 2009

I use vswprintf per RAD Studio's Help (F1) :

```
int vswprintf(wchar_t *buffer, const wchar_t *format, va_list arglist);
```

Up to now I always provided a big buffer `wchar_t OutputStr[1000]` and never had any issues.  As a test and wanting to do an improvement action, I tried a small buffer `wchar_t OutputStr[12]` and noticed that the program crashes entirely.  Even `try{}catch(...){}` doesn't catch it.  Codeguard reports that a `memcpy()` fails, which seems to be the internal implementation. I had expected an `EOF` as return value instead.

When searching online for `vswprintf` I find the c++ variant takes a buffer size as input, but I can't seem to convince my compiler to use that variant ?
Any idea how to force it using BCB2009 ?

The whole point of the exercise was to implement a fall back scenario for when the buffer is too small in possibly one or two freak situations, so that I can allocate more memory for the function and try again.  But this mechanism doesn't seem to work at all.

Not sure how to best test for the exact amount of bytes/characters needed either ?

Comment: All of the non-buffer size specified *sprintf...* functions have this problem.  There is no way for the function to know the actual buffer size, so no way for them to `raise()` an error when they exceed it.

Comment: perhaps try `_vsnwprintf`

Comment: @M.M `_vsnwprintf` works.  Thanks !  Any idea how I can check how many bytes/characters I need in case the buffer is too small ?  `vsnwprintf_s` would have been good for that but it's not included in c++Builder 2009

Comment: @Peter calling it with `0` for the size should return the size required, without writing anything

Comment: @M.M  I tried that but it doesn't work.  The MS documentation online also doesn't mention it. ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx )

Comment: Isn't it fantastic when compiler vendors roll their own worse versions of standard functions..:)  another option available to you is to get a freeware source implementation of the standard version of `vswprintf`.

Comment: @M.M  It's what keeps us busy, right :)  I might actually simply increase the buffer to a silly size and do it that way, for the few freak incidents that may happen.  Unless the perfect function is just around the corner of course.

Comment: @M.M see comment I made to the proposed answer below: `vsnprintf`

Comment: @M.M I meant `vsnwprintf` (sorry about that).  It's a mess.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [vswprintf_s](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Vsprintf_s,_vswprintf_s). It returns negative value on failure

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I need, yet BCB2009 doesn't seem to know this function ?  Was this added in later versions ? (`stdio.h` included)

Comment: Right. [The Secure C Library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Secure_C_Library) was added in C++Builder 2010

Comment: `_vsnwprintf` seems to do the trick.  Now to find how many bytes/characters I need in case the buffer is not big enough ...

Comment: @Peter [_vsnwprintf](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Vsnprintf,_vsnwprintf) if nsize is 0, returns the number of bytes needed, not including the terminating '\0' character.

Comment: I'm afraid not.  Not according to my testing (returns -1) and not according to the MS docs ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101834/discussion-between-jacob-seleznev-and-peter).

Comment: if I use `vsnprintf` (without the leading underscore) it works as well but this function always returns the required amount of characters, whether the buffer is large enough or not.  So in fact an easy way to check and immediately allocate enough memory.  I can't find proper documentation for this one, I happened to stumble on it because of a typo ... imagine ...

Comment: @M.M I meant `vsnwprintf` (sorry about that).